# Using Angular JS, Jquery and Metismenu together

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to use Jquery, AngularJs and metisMenu together.

At first, I included `Jquery` first then `AngularJs` and then `metisMenu`. But metisMenu didn't work well.

After that I re-order them I include `AngularJs` first then `Jquery`and `metisMenu` last. It work

Can you guy explain to me why i have to include `Jquery` after `AngularJs`?

Comment: Probably the metisMenu jquery code runs first and your views are dynamically loaded later.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS uses jqlite by default. If you include jQuery before AngularJS, Angular will use jQuery.

If you include AngularJS first then jQuery, Angular will use jqlite, but you can still access jQuery with `$`.

Maybe metisMenu depends on jqlite or something in Angular that will be overwritten by jQuery. That is why it doesn't work if you include jQuery first.